# Scala scala.MatchError: 22.22 (of class java.lang.Float)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading data from Hbase and creating RRD of SQL Row with following code.

```
val getFormattedRDD = hbaseRawRDD.map(data => {

  //set column family
  val colFamily = Bytes.toBytes("0")

  var dataBuffer = ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]
  dataBuffer += new String(data._1.get)
  tableSchema.map { column =>
    {
      var dataBytes = data._2.getValue(colFamily, Bytes.toBytes(column.columnName))

      if (dataBytes != null) {
        if (column.dataType == "INT") {              
          dataBuffer += (Bytes.toInt(dataBytes) ^ -2147483648)              
        }
        if (column.dataType == "FLOAT") {                           
          dataBuffer += (Bytes.toFloat(dataBytes))           
        }           
        else {
          dataBuffer += new String(dataBytes)
        }
      } else {
        dataBuffer += null
      }
    }
  }
  Row.fromSeq(dataBuffer)
})
```

In RDD appearing fine for float as 22.22 but when I create DataFrame from that with following command.

```
val dfResults = sqlContext.createDataFrame(getFormattedRDD, dataframeSchema)
dfResults.show
```

it throws error...

> scala.MatchError: 22.22 (of class java.lang.Float)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)

Schema for data-frame is:

```
StructField(KEY,StringType,true)
StructField(PRODUCT_TYPE,StringType,true)
StructField(REGION_KEY,StringType,true)
StructField(BUSINESS_UNIT,StringType,true)
StructField(AMOUNT,IntegerType,true)
StructField(PERCENTAGE,FloatType,true)
StructField(CUSTOMER_ID,StringType,true)
```